# Google Analytics Get Records Where Custom Dimension is Not Set

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, universal-analytics

I'm using Google APIs to retrieve data from Google Analytics with a Custom Dimension.  This works well; however, I also have the need to get the data that does NOT have the custom dimension set...

The way's I've seen the Custom Dimension thus far is only to show records where that dimension is set.  That makes sense with the domain vocabulary; however, my case and I'm sure others will need access the other slice of the pie.

Is there any way to get a report that includes data with and without the custom dimension being set?

If not is there a way to get a report that contains data that does NOT have the dimension set?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to report on both cases and then programmatically figure out the exclusion set.

Another (possibly simpler) way would be to always set the custom dimension to a value. The API uses the value `(not set)` in many dimensions for exactly this purpose. You could instantiate your tracker objects with the custom dimension initially set to `(not set)` and then reassign when you have a real value. That way all hits would have *some* value set.

Comment: I'd thought about building a process for retrieving an exclusion set...  I hadn't thought about forcing the param to be set to something like empty string or null which would most likely work...  Thanks for the solutions.  I guess I'm left asking still if there is native functionality to achieve my goal???  It would seem that I wouldn't have to force an empty data param or perform some manual data work to get seemingly a simple result...

Comment: At this time there is no native way to achieve your goal. It's possible support for that may be added to future versions of the API.

Comment: Ok, thanks again for the tips Philip and that does fully answer my question.

Comment: Also, I ended up defaulting a value on the dimension.

Comment: FWIW this will also help you be sure it's working, as there can still be hits with no value at all, which lets you discern between hits that are validly "not set" and ones where the dimension was missing for other reasons (the situation I'm currently trapped in, where my dimension that should always be present is often missing).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @philip-walton, there is no way to segment on the "not defined" custom dimension bucket (or custom metric for what it's worth).

You could manually set it to `(not set)` prior to anything else in your code and override them with the right value when the time comes BUT that would be a big problem if you're using session or user level custom dimensions.

The principle of those dimensions is : you set them up once and forget about them.

If you set a session level custom dimension to `(not set)` on each page prior to sending the hit to GA, you would override this value for all the user's sessions, even for the hits prior to one one you're about to send.

You could initialize the user or session level custom dimension to `(not set)` but that would require a complex setup using cookies or session storage to remember not to override it if it has been set in your session / user lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, unlike adobe analytics which provides a (none) bucket for all cases where a dimension was not set, GA only reports back on the cases where it was set. In the interface you can more readily see % of sessions addressed by the data, but via the API there is no "all other" dimension.

If you give me your precise use case I can try and think of a workaround using segmentation or something else.

Jeff

Comment: Thanks for the response Jeff.  The use case is that I'm reporting on revenue data from adsense which is linked to a custom dimension.  The custom dimension is supposed to ONLY be set on the first page visit and thereafter the revenue goes into a "general bucket".  The problem is I can easily retrieve all the revenue that has the custom dimension set, but trying to get access to the data that does NOT have the dimension set is proving to be more difficult than should be.